# Tub not draining, despite entire trip drain assembly removed?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drain, bathtub

A friend of mine flipped the drain in my tub closed, which probably hasn't been done in a decade or more. Unfortunately, flipping it back to open has not allowed the water to drain. I've already removed the trip drain assembly including the plug (basically all of this: https://www.homedepot.com/p/DANCO-Tub-Drain-Linkage-Assembly-88924/202950216 )

It wasn't draining slowly or anything yesterday, so I really don't think it's a hair clog or anything like that. I assume there has to be a part of the drain or something down there, but I really have no idea what it could be. Does anyone know what might be down there and how to get it out?

Edit: To be clear, everything, including the drum, came out as an assembly.

Comment: Its possibly blocked

Comment: push it down in the drain with screwdriver

Comment: Did everything come out as an assembly, even the drum at the end ?

Comment: If it hasn't been touched in a decade, it may be corroded enough that the lever arm which controls the drain valve has broken free. In which case the fixes (unless you can somehow just poke it back into draining position) start with getting access to that linkage...

Answer (score 2):

If everything, including the bucket (drum) that is what actually stops the drain up came out, then you probably have a clog that's been brewing for 10 years and got shifted into position when the drain was moved.

Stuff a rag into a plastic bag into the overflow opening and go wild with a plunger, for a first step. Use a big enough rag that the improvised overflow blocker can't get sucked into the pipe and cause more fun, or have an assistant hold onto it.